# Random behavior on button click at times in Android App

Tags: android, sqlite, concurrency, publish-subscribe, event-bus

Not sure how should I phrase it, but In my app sometimes a single button click generates multiple events and hence it ends up sending multiple similar transactions to the server which is causing data integrity problem. Here is the code flow, Do note that this code runs on users phone which may have weaker connections at times, hence I store the data in SQLite and there is a separate sync service which sends data (fetching from SQLite tables) to Server when Internet is connected.

This is where the click is captured and event is posted for Main Activity (Landing Page)

```
@OnClick(R.id.btn_add_attempt)
    public void onAttemptClick() {
      try{
         btnAddAttempt.setEnabled(false);
         EventBus.getDefault().post(new ExampleActionEvent());
         moveToHomePage();
      } catch (Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
         Crashlytics.logException(e);
      }
 }
```

Here is the Event subscription from my main Activity.

```
@Subscribe()
    public void onExampleAction(ExampleActionEvent exampleActionEvent)
    {
        if(application == null) application = (ExApplication) getApplication();

        final Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                ArrayList<Something> somethings = application.getArray().getsomethings();
                if (!ExUtils.validatesomethings(somethings)){
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            RiderUtils.showSimplePopup(
                                    MainLandingActivity.this,
                                    getString(R.string.title_alert),
                                    getString(R.string.alert_message),
                                    getString(R.string.done),
                                    null,
                                    false,
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            showPendingSomething();
                                            ExUtils.moveToPending(MainLandingActivity.this);
                                        }
                                          },
                                    null,
                                    false);
                        }
                    });
                    return;
                }
                status = application.getArray().getStatus();

                imageLocalPath = application.getArray().getsomethings().get(0).getPhotoPath();

                Log.d(Const.TAG, "image path is: "+imageLocalPath);

                try {
                    ExUtils.pushExampleActionEvent(application.getArray(), MainLandingActivity.this, xyz, abc);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                FileWriteEvent fileWriteEvent = null;
                String currentTimestamp = application.getArray().getTimestamp();

                switch (status) {
                    case Const.UPDATE_SUCCESS:
                        fileWriteEvent = new FileWriteEvent(Const.EVENT_CSV_FILE_SUCCESS_VALUE, application.getArray(), "",
                                cachedLocation, currentTimestamp, null);
                        break;
                    case Const.UPDATE_ATTEMPTED:
                        fileWriteEvent = new FileWriteEvent(Const.EVENT_CSV_FILE_ATTEMPTED_VALUE, riderApplication.getBulkArray(), "",
                                cachedLocation, currentTimestamp, null);
                        ExUtils.showSnackbar(holder, getString(R.string.Example), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                        break;
                }

                if(fileWriteEvent != null)
                {
                    EventBus.getDefault().post(fileWriteEvent);
                }

                createAll();    //SQLite DB call for Inserting some data

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            switch (status) {
                                case Const.UPDATE_SUCCESS:
                                    RiderUtils.showSnackbar(holder, getString(R.string.Success), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                                    break;
                                case Const.UPDATE_ATTEMPTED:
                                    RiderUtils.showSnackbar(holder, getString(R.string.Failed), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                                    break;
                            }
                        }catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        thread.start();
    }
```

I am not able to figure out why is it misbehaving sometimes randomly otherwise it runs smoothly, Hence I am not able to regenrate the issue while debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after sometimes I looked at the problem again and found out the developer who worked before me had not declared the Main Activity as SingleInstance and hence Every time if the app was opened from Notification Drawer as we were showing it in Notification drawer if app is running, then it was creating a new Activity hence registering on EventBus which was causing the issue by creating duplicate events.